# Read special keys in linux terminal without clearing screen

Tags: python, python-3.x, terminal, ncurses, python-curses

I have a program where I simply need to read special keys in a linux terminal (both xterm and console). Currently I am using the [`curses`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html#module-curses) to do it (though I absolutely do not need curses for anything else), and it works perfectly except for the one nuisance: I do not want curses to clear the screen and change the CRLF mode.

That is, this code would do it:

```
stdscr = curses.initscr()
curses.cbreak()
curses.noecho()
stdscr.keypad(1)

while True:
    c = stdscr.getch()
    if c == curses.KEY_UP:
        scroll_up()
    elif c == curses.KEY_DOWN:
        scroll_down()
```

but the complication is that it will clear the screen and previous content on the terminal is not seen; also all output from background processes will have newlines converted to linefeed only.

I know I can turn the terminal into uncooked mode myself, delay after `ESC` character, and so, but I want this program to work with special keys such as <kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>↑</kbd> consistently, on all terminals, and as such it would be PITA

Thus is there any way to either

- Avoid clearing screen with curses and changing the newline mode (I read that the function `newterm` of ncurses could be used for it, but it is not implemented by Python), **or**
- Any way to restore the original screen after it was cleared and manually restore the CRLF behavior and such, **or**
- Any other simple way of consistently reading special keys in Linux?

Comment: Maybe have a look at `https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pyrepl`.  It is curses-based but doesn't clear the screen.

Comment: Looks interesting, but it wasn't quite obvious how to hook it in here, should I instantiate UnixConsole?

Comment: ah, prepare(), and get_event(). Now just how do I change the newline back to CRLF? :D would you want to make this into an answer ;)

Comment: EXCEPT that it did not decode arrow keys :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Moved from the comments)

Maybe have a look at `https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pyrepl`. It is curses-based but doesn't clear the screen.  The applications `pythoni` and `pythoni1` give a Python prompt that doesn't use `readline`, but present a similarish interface, with a few extras like multiline editing (in case we try to type a multiline command).

To answer your latest comment: the arrow keys work for me in `pythoni` and `pythoni1`...

Comment: I am going to accept this answer, as indeed it worked beautifully. However in this case we ended up reading the `hidraw0` device instead.